# Im getting this error, ReactFreshWebpackPlugin doesnt support webpack 5, so what can i do to fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

```
Error: ReactFreshWebpackPlugin does not support webpack v5.
    at ReactFreshWebpackPlugin.apply (C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin.js:69:23)      
    at webpack (C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\next\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:51:13)
    at C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\next\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:36:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpack (C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\next\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:36:24)
    at HotReloader.start (C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\hot-reloader.js:15:2011)
    at async DevServer.prepare (C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js:10:2363)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\shopify-testapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node server.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jaydev\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-05T07_42_32_223Z-debug.log
```

Comment: when do you get this error? can you explain a bit on what do you do which gets you this error?

Comment: I just did npm run dev, my server wil begin to start up and then I get this error

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, I downgraded webpack and now I can run my server again

Comment: I have this problem ,  what are you did ?

Comment: which version of webpack did you used?